# How to obtain firefox user agent string?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, npapi

I'm building an add-on for FireFox that simulates a website, but running from a local library. (If you want to know more, [look here](http://xxm.sf.net/))

I'm looking for a way to get a hold of the user-agent string that FireFox *would* send if it were doing plain http. I'm doing the nsIProtocolHandler myself and serve my own implementation of nsIHttpChannel, so if I have [a peek at the source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/netwerk/protocol/http/src/nsHttpHandler.cpp#535), it looks like I'll have to do all the work myself.

Unless there's a contract/object-id on nsHttpHandler I could use to create an instance just for a brief moment to get the UserAgent? (Though I notice I'll need to call `Init()` because it does `InitUserAgentComponents()` and hope it'll get to there... And I guess the http protocol handler does the channels and handlers so there won't be a contract to nsHttpHandler directly.)

If I have a little *peek over the wall* I notice this globally available call [ObtainUserAgentString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does just this in that parallel dimension...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it via XPCOM like this:

```
var httpHandler = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http"].
  getService(Ci.nsIHttpProtocolHandler);
var userAgent = httpHandler.userAgent;
```

Comment: Same works in C++ of course: `nsCOMPtr<nsIHttpProtocolHandler> httpHandler(do_GetService("@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http")); httpHandler->GetUserAgent(userAgent);`

Comment: happen to know what do_GetService does? I've got this for now but throws an unsupported interface: `NS_GetServiceManager(SvcMgr);SvcMgr.GetServiceByContractID(NS_IHTTPPROTOCOLHANDLER_CONTRACT,nsIHttpProtocolHandler,h);`

Comment: Are you defining NS_IHTTPPROTOCOLHAND‌​LER_CONTRACT yourself? What is the value?

Comment: `@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=http` in the mean time I've discovered nsIHttpProtocolHandler has been changing IID's in recent versions. I'll try to pick up the right one from http://mxr.mozilla.org/ ...

Comment: yes! got this one to work: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsIHttpProtocolHandler.idl Don't know if this one is going to keep changing with each release? perhaps I should propose a nsIUserAgentBuilder or something.

Comment: They change the IID if the interface changes. Best thing is to use JavaScript if at all possible.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with testing (and updating the rdf) with each FF release, so I'll check the IID each time. I'll fallback to the firefox.exe version info just in case, it's not that important really. Not sure how to call javascript from XPCOM, though, but that's a totally different crusade...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript. But frankly I'd be surprised if you can't get by with writing everything is JS and using js-ctypes to call into native code.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Firefox [changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/User_Agent_Strings_Reference) how this was done in version 4.  Have you tried:

```
alert(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: I'm not running on javascript, is there a XPCOM way to the navigator object?

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you actaully do need to use NPAPI like you suggest in your tags, you can use [NPN_UserAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_UserAgent) to get it; however, I would be shocked if you actually needed to do that just for an extension. Most likely Anthony's answer is more what you're looking for.